# What's the best way to load a ML model with Django

Tags: django, django-views, bert-language-model

I'm deploying a Machine Learning model (Named Entity Recognition) with Django. In short, the user chooses a field (Politics or Science for example) and writes a text in a search area. Then the model identifies the named entities in the text.

My problem is that the ML model (encoder) is loaded each time the view is triggered, which slows down the process. Any idea how to optimize this and load it only once ?

My views.py :

```
def search_view(request):

   if request.POST: 
          field = request.POST['field']
          query = request.POST['query']
          encoder = load_encoder(field)
          results = Ner_model(query,encoder)
          context['result'] = results
   return render(request,'ner/results.html', context)
```

Load encoder function:

```
def load_encoder(field):
 path_encoder = os.paths.join(field,'field_encoder')
 encoder = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(path_encoder)
 return encoder
```

Thanks!

Comment: two questions: 1- how is `Ner_model` called? 2- where did you deploy this django project? on your local machine or shared host or vps?

Comment: 1- It's a Bert model fine tuned for NER. 2- It's only on my local machine for the moment, but I plan to host it on a website

Comment: Can you add this part (loading Ner_model) to your codes as well?

Comment: Done. It's a bert huggingface model

Comment: loading `Ner_model` is much more time consuming than loading `encoder`. So it's better to load all possible models at first if you have enough RAM on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to load all possible encoders and models at first. then for each condition, call proper model. for example if you have 2 fields:

```
encoders = {}
fields = [field1, field2]
for field in fields:
    path_encoder = os.path.join(field,'field_encoder')
    encoder = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(path_encoder)
    encoders[field] = encoder

def load_encoder(field):
    encoder = encoders.get(field)
    return encoder
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I've already tried it : loading the encoders and calling them in the search_view function. The problem is that this first loading takes so much time, which is not desirable for the end user

Comment: It might be a way with the "ready" method.. I'm looking this up!

Comment: The time for running the server at the beginning is long, but when the server is up, all requests of end users are respond immediately

Comment: And where the first part of your suggestion would be (loading all encoders before the function) ? outside of the views.py ?

Comment: Yes. your codes would be cleaner if you create a new file and place the loader there.

Comment: Thanks! since I don't want to fill the memory by loading all encoders, I've got inspired by your suggestion and found a workaround, that I'll explain in next post :)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Masoud's suggestion, I defined 2 global variables : one that would store the encoder loaded and one to keep track of the field chosen.. even though global variables are generally not so recommended..

So that gives something like this :

```
encoder = None
old_field = ''

def search_view(request):
   global encoder
   global old_field

   if request.POST: 
          field = request.POST['field']
          query = request.POST['query']
          if (not encoder) or (old_field!=field):
              encoder = load_encoder(field)
          results = Ner_model(query,encoder)
          context['result'] = results
  
   return render(request,'ner/results.html', context)
```